# Why the ping pong is not working on the waypoints?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The goal is when pressing the P key make a ping pong nonstop between the next waypoint and the last waypoint. including if the P key pressed when the transform start moving from his original position so make a ping pong between the first waypoint and the transform original position.

The way it is now when I press the P key the whole game is freezing the editor is freezing and I need to shut it down.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Waypoints : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> WayPoints;

    private int CurrentWayPoint = 0;
    private bool IsPatrolling = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartPatrol();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            ReversePatrolWayPoints();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            PingPong();
        }
    }

    public void StartPatrol()
    {
        if (!IsPatrolling)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Patrol());
        }
    }

    public void ReversePatrolWayPoints()
    {
        WayPoints.Reverse();
    }

    bool pingPongEnabled = false;
    Vector3 pingPongStart;
    public void PingPong()
    {
        pingPongEnabled = true;
        pingPongStart = transform.position;
    }

    private IEnumerator Patrol()
    {
        if (WayPoints == null || WayPoints.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waypoints list is null or empty");
            yield break;
        }

        IsPatrolling = true;

        while (CurrentWayPoint < WayPoints.Count)
        {
            if (pingPongEnabled)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(pingPongStart, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 1, 1) * Time.deltaTime);
                continue;
            }

            float distanceToWayPoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * 1f);

            if (distanceToWayPoint <= 1f)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("Reached Waypoint {0}", CurrentWayPoint);
                CurrentWayPoint++;
                if (CurrentWayPoint >= WayPoints.Count)
                {
                    CurrentWayPoint = 0;
                }
            }

            yield return null;
        }

        IsPatrolling = false;
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Edit :
This is the script after the changes :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> WayPoints;

    private int CurrentWayPoint = 0;
    private bool IsPatrolling = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartPatrol();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            ReversePatrolWayPoints();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            PingPong();
        }
    }

    public void StartPatrol()
    {
        if (!IsPatrolling)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Patrol());
        }
    }

    public void ReversePatrolWayPoints()
    {
        WayPoints.Reverse();
    }

    bool pingPongEnabled = false;
    Vector3 pingPongStart;
    public void PingPong()
    {
        pingPongEnabled = true;
        pingPongStart = transform.position;
    }

    private IEnumerator Patrol()
    {
        if (WayPoints == null || WayPoints.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waypoints list is null or empty");
            yield break;
        }

        IsPatrolling = true;

        while (CurrentWayPoint < WayPoints.Count)
        {
            if (pingPongEnabled)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pingPongStart, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
                yield return null;
            }

            float distanceToWayPoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position);
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * 1f);

            if (distanceToWayPoint <= 1f)
            {
                Debug.LogFormat("Reached Waypoint {0}", CurrentWayPoint);
                CurrentWayPoint++;
                if (CurrentWayPoint >= WayPoints.Count)
                {
                    CurrentWayPoint = 0;
                }
            }

            yield return null;
        }

        IsPatrolling = false;
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Edit :

This is working almost as I wanted :

When it's making the ping pong it's doing between the last transform position and the next waypoint position and I wanted it to be between the last waypoint and the next waypoint. but the ping pong is now working.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Mover : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> WayPoints;

    private int CurrentWayPoint = 0;
    private bool IsPatrolling = false;

    private void Start()
    {
        StartPatrol();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R))
        {
            ReversePatrolWayPoints();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            PingPong();
        }
    }

    public void StartPatrol()
    {
        if (!IsPatrolling)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Patrol());
        }
    }

    public void ReversePatrolWayPoints()
    {
        WayPoints.Reverse();
    }

    bool pingPongEnabled = false;
    Vector3 pingPongStart;
    public void PingPong()
    {
        pingPongEnabled = true;
        pingPongStart = transform.position;
    }

    private IEnumerator Patrol()
    {
        if (WayPoints == null || WayPoints.Count == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Waypoints list is null or empty");
            yield break;
        }

        IsPatrolling = true;

        while (CurrentWayPoint < WayPoints.Count)
        {
            if (pingPongEnabled)
            {
                transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pingPongStart, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
                yield return null;
            }
            else
            {
                float distanceToWayPoint = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position);
                transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, Time.deltaTime * 1f);

                if (distanceToWayPoint <= 1f)
                {
                    Debug.LogFormat("Reached Waypoint {0}", CurrentWayPoint);
                    CurrentWayPoint++;
                    if (CurrentWayPoint >= WayPoints.Count)
                    {
                        CurrentWayPoint = 0;
                    }
                }

                yield return null;
            }
        }

        IsPatrolling = false;
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Comment: For starters, you call StartPatrol() only in the Start() method. Also call it in the Update() method after calling PingPong();.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor freezes because in the case that `pingPongEnabled` is set to `true` you do

```
if (pingPongEnabled)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(pingPongStart, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 1, 1) * Time.deltaTime);
    continue;
}
```

without `yield`ing within the loop -> due to `continue` it immediately goes to the next iteration without the exit condition ever fulfilled.

You want to make sure to always do

```
if (pingPongEnabled)
{
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(pingPongStart, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 1, 1) * Time.deltaTime);     
    yield return null;
    continue;
}
```

in order to at least wait until the next frame with the next iteration

---

Anyway, this

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(pingPongStart, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time * 1, 1) * Time.deltaTime);
```

doesn't really "ping-pong" like you would probably expect. It always starts back at `pingPongStart` and moves a single step towards the waypoint and only goes a bit further or less.

You probably rather ment

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(pingPongStart, WayPoints[CurrentWayPoint].transform.position, Mathf.PingPong(Time.time, 1));
```

Comment: you can't make continue; and then yield return null; if you make first continue; it will not reach the yield return null. did you mean to put only yield return null; instead the continue ?

Comment: I changed everything like in your answer but when I'm pressing on the P key now the object get crazy and looks like "jumping" change positions very quick and make a ping pong between two positions then again change positions quick.

Comment: I edited my question with the changes I did to the script but it's not working good yet.

Comment: Ok, now it's almost working like I wanted but at least now the ping pong is working.  I edited my question again and added the last version of the script.  almost perfect as I wanted.